# OptionsMenu does not get created and kills the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

The problem is, that if I press the hardware button for the OptionsMenu, the app freezes and after a half second the fragment view disappears. There is **no LogCat error**, this is some kind of confusing me. The menu is not working in one out of six fragments. Same problem happens in every fragment.

I want to create an OptionsMenu with the following code.
The OptionsMenu is created in the activity, where the fragments get shown.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns true
    // then it has handled the app icon touch event

    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            add();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_logoff:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


}
```

**XML: main_activity_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_logoff"
        android:title="Ausloggen"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

I tried switching around the return statment to **true** and **super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);** but nothing changes. The App is developed for Android 2.3

Comment: are you sure actionBarDrawerToggle is not null?

Comment: `actionBarDrawerToggle` may not initialised..

Comment: @blackbelt Yes, it's initialised in the onCreate with actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are some problems with the hardwarebutton and Fragments in Android version < 3.0.

Here is a guide, how to implement a Actionbar with a softwarebased solution:
http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/

Comment: Thanks, this is an alternative solution to the OptionsMenu. Even though it does not solve the original problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) instead true

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: OptionsMenu does still not open, the fragment is freezing for a half second and does dissappear in the end

Comment: Are you trying to use fragments in Android 2.3 ?? Fragments available for Android 3.0+ Only

Comment: You also can try to change android:theme parameter to any else, maybe it fix your problem

Comment: Yes, I'm working with fragments and the support.v4 and they are working perfectly. The theme is already changed to the version from the support.v4. 

I kinda solved my problem with the actionbar posted above.